# What will happen with a domain user if I quit the domain?

Tags: windows, login, domain

I bought my old laptop from my company. It has Windows 10 installed and I do not want to reinstall it. This computer is still in the corporate domain but there is trouble with Windows updates on it: I cannot change settings because of its domain policy.

I have a domain user that I use to login with. This one is a local admin. 
If I exit the current domain will I be able to login with this domain user? This is a domain user and I'm scared that I can't login anymore if I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you remove the computer from the domain you will no longer be able to logon using your domain user account. Therefore you should create a new *local* user account for continued use of the computer:

1. Create a new local user account. Make it an Administrator
2. Login with the new local admin account.
3. Optionally, copy any files from the domain user account you want to keep. (The domain user's profile folders *won't* be removed from the machine when the PC is removed from the domain, but as noted above you won't be able to logon to the account directly to access them.)
4. Remove the computer from the domain.